# My HTML content do not display when I use Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I use a script for getting the content from a specific url using ajax, my HTML content is not displayed, i.e my table element is not displayed: I get the data from the specif url and I am showing it in an alert box, and also using `document.write` to write on the page the data coming from the url I called:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"http://your url",
      success: onSuccess,
      error:onError
    });
  });
  function onSuccess(data){
    var servertext=data;
    document.write(servertext);
    alert(servertext);
  }
  function onError(data){
    alert(data+'error');
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> hello</p>
  <table height="150px" weight="150px" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="green.png" height="100px" width="100px" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.write` shouldn't be used after the page has finished loading. If you call it, it will implicitly call `document.open`, which blanks the page and creates a new document.

Comment: my problem is my html elementi.e the table show in code is not dispalyed

Comment: do u mean to say document.open(servertext);

Comment: @lenda You should not use `document.write` once the page is loaded.  The call to `document.write` is **destroying the entire page** and creating a new page with only your Ajax content.  If you want to avoid destroying all the content on your page, **don't use `document.write`** after the page has loaded.

Comment: @ APSILLERS YOU R RI8 THNKS THIS WORKS

Answer (score 1):

If your `servertext` is html then try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"http://your url",
                success: onSuccess,        
                error:onError                   
            });          
    });
    function onSuccess(data){
        var servertext=data;

        $("div#ajaxContent").html(servertext);

        alert(servertext);
    }
    function onError(data){
    alert(data+'error');

    }       
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> heloo</p>
     <table height="150px" weight="150px" border="1px">     
        <tr>
            <td> <img src="green.png" height="100px" width="100px" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="ajaxContent"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: my problem is my html element i.e the table show in code is not dispalyed

Comment: Have you tried `$("div#ajaxContent").html(servertext)`? It will render any html returned by your ajax call.

Comment: do u understood my question i thing u r not clear abt my question and this do not work

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVxwe/ (I had to change the Ajax call to use jsfiddle's echo API, since I don't have access to your Ajax target page, but otherwise all code is that same.)  Did you add the `<div id="ajaxContent"></div>` at the bottom of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write` as it won't work and wrong.

Instead, add some placeholder element to your HTML then assign the response:

```
document.getElementById("myplaceholder").innerHTML = servertext;
```

This will put the response in element defined as:

```
<div id="myplaceholder"></div>
```

Also note you can send request only to pages under the same domain as the page having the AJAX code in it. ([Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

Comment: my problem is my html element i.e the table show in code is not dispalyed

Comment: <table height="150px" weight="150px" border="1px">     
        <tr>
            <td> <img src="green.png" height="100px" width="100px" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 this is not displayed in my page the body content id i remove my script this table will be is displayed